# how to excel to datagridview ,it's empty

Tags: database, excel

[image]
[image]

(button1)

```
         OpenFileDialog OpenFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (OpenFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {

            textBox_path.Text = OpenFile.FileName;
```

(button2)

```
        string PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + 
        textBox_path.Text +"; Extended Properties =\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;\";";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + textBox_SheetName.Text + "$]", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

My question is 
I import data of excel to datagridview ,and then it was only increase a empty row. please help me.

Comment: First use breakpoints and the debugger to see if `myDataAdapter` has any rows in it. Do you know how to debug VBA?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [POST Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you